# How to pass variable to ColourBox Inline popup?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, colorbox

How to pass dynamic variable to ColorBox `inline` pop up and access it from PHP code in Pop Up window?

**HTML**

```
<a class="inline" href="#popup">Open Popup</a>

<div style="display: none">
<div class="popup">Pop up contents</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, transition:'none',speed:'10', close:'close', opacity:'0.6'});
});
```

Comment: In order to access something from PHP you need to execute a php script and sending it argumenst via GET or POST (or if you have someing stored in a session). It looks like your href is only referensing a part on the current page that is already processed by php. You could load a php snippet from colorbox using ajax and sening it arg via a GET reqeust.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, what you want is to pass the contents inside the `<div class="popup">`. Right? One change, I think, you should make first, is to change the `<div class="popup">` to `<div id="popup">`, since in the  tag you're referencing an id (#popup).

Then, in the jquery code, you should access the contents of the div inside the colorbox the following way (at least this is how I do it):

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, href:function(){ return $(this).attr('href'); }, transition:'none',speed:'10', close:'close', opacity:'0.6'});
});
```

The $(this).attr('href') should return #popup, and in consequence show inside the colorbox the contents of the popup.

For the second part, to access some content inside a PHP, what I have on my site, is that when a user clicks a link, the Jquery gets the Id of the element clicked, and populates an `<input type="hidden">` that I have inside a `<form>`. This way:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.colorbox({ "SOME-OPTIONS", onComplete:function(){ $('input[name=web]').val($(this).attr('id'));}
});
```

This way, once the colorbox has loaded (onComplete), a hidden input inside my FORM (`<input type="hidden" id="web" name="web" value="">`)gets the value that I want to be accessed afterwards in my PHP, once the form is submitted. This way:

**PHP**

```
$pageRefresh = $_POST['web'];
```

Hope it helps. At least a little bit :)